# Post data to server with okhttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp

How can I post data from my android app to php server with okhttp? Is it even possible? I've been able to retrieve data from the server, but I need to send String from my application to the server.

Thanks.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(requestUrl).build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    try {
        Response response = call.execute();
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            Log.v("LOGV", response.body().string());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("LOGV", e.getMessage().toString());
    }
```

Comment: Well I've been only able to retrieve data from my server, I am adding the code in my post now. I can't even find how to post string from my device to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example from okhttp website:

```
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"); //defines the type of the body 

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body) //include the body in the request with the POST method
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

And a link to their github repo with similar example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/guide/PostExample.java

Comment: Yeah, whit this code I am only getting my html website from the server. I need reverse from this.